# PHP Login Form No Database

Tags: php, forms, authentication, passwords

This form does not submit but I am trying to get it to redirect to a page if the password is correct and if not then go to the home page. I am also trying to put in a remember me cookie feature. A little help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
<?php
     if($logged_in){header('Location: index.php');}
    function checkLogin(){
       /* Check if user has been remembered */
       if(isset($_COOKIE['cookpass'])){
          $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['cookpass'];
       }

       /* Username and password have been set */
       if(isset($_SESSION['password'])){
          /* Confirm that username and password are valid */
          if($_SESSION['password'] != 'password'){
             /* Variables are incorrect, user not logged in */
             unset($_SESSION['password']);
             return false;
          }
          return true;
       }
       /* User not logged in */
       else{
          return false;
       }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
        //Set Variables
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($password == 'password'){
        $md5pass = md5($password);
        $_SESSION['password'] = $md5pass;
          if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
          setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
       }
    }
    }
    echo 'Not Logged In';
    $logged_in = checkLogin();
    ?>
```

Form:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Password: &nbsp;<input name="password" type="password" /><br/><br/>
    Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" />
    <input name="sublogin" type="submit" value="Login" style="float:right;" />

    <br/>
      <p></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not starting a session. If you're going to use session variables on PHP you must start them by using `session_start()` at the beginning of the page, before the headers are sent. Also the form doesn't have a valid action.

Read some samples on login forms, there are a lot on the internet. I think your approach to the problem is not the best or the easiest one...

Comment: how would i do php self if i wanted to keep it on one page